# MFMailComposer custom buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I know it is possible to change the navbar image on a MFMailComposer. Is it possible to customize the Cancel and Send buttons too? I want to use custom images for the backgrounds of the buttons so just changing the tint won't do.

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT**

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Navbar with custom buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing them through `mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.items`, which is an array of the bar items.